# Using Google Maps API to avoid certain states

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to be able to calculate a route between two cities and have different states blacklisted? So for instance if I want to travel from Las Vegas, NV and want to end up in Cheyenne, WY without crossing into Utah (going east through Arizona and up through Colorado instead)?

Comment: [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's been a request since 2008.. Probably not going to happen then.